# How to get site physical path with appcmd

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe

I am trying the following appcmd commnad:

```
appcmd list app /site.name:"misechko.com.ua-DEV" /xml | appcmd list vdir /in /text:physicalPath
```

misechko.com.ua-DEV is a correct site name in IIS. appcmd is registered in path;

I get the following error output when I am trying to execute a command in cmd.exe:

> ERROR ( hresult:8007000d, message:The input contained an error
>   element, which may indicate that the operationproducing the input has
>   failed. )

What is the mistake in the app setup? I guess I am mixing a cmd and powershell approach, but the abocementioned script doesn't work in PowerShell either. A PowerShell way of getting the path by web site name is preferable.

P.S. My PowerShell alternative that also doesn't work:

```
$appCmd = "$Env:SystemRoot\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"

$appcmd list app /site.name:"misechko.com.ua-DEV" /xml | $appcmd list vdir /in /text:physicalPath
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Researched myself and found an solution:

```
     function GetPhysicalPath ([String]$siteName) {

        function Get-PipelineInput
        {
            end {
                [xml]$appConfigXml = $input
                return $appConfigXml.application.virtualDirectory.physicalPath
            }
        }

        $appCmd = "$Env:SystemRoot\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"  

        return & $appCmd list app /site.name:"$siteName" /config | Get-PipelineInput
    }
```

Comment: Nice solution. Have to be careful though, since `appcmd list app ...` will return all virtual directories as siblings i.e. it will break the XML parser.

If you're only interested in the root of the site, better to use "vdir" `$appCmd list vdir "$siteName/" /config` (note the trailing slash on site name), and then tweak the xml path to suit i.e.  `$appConfigXml.virtualDirectory.physicalPath`

Answer (score 3):

This also worked for me. running cmd as admin.

```
appcmd list app /site.name:"Default Web Site" /path:"/" /xml | appcmd list vdir /in /text:physicalPath
```

[source](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tom/2008/04/01/useful-appcmd-commands/)